# Is Jesus still in His human state as at Revelation 1? And is He till now?

Tags: jesus, revelation

The Revelation 1:1 TLV

> The revelation of Yeshua the Messiah, which God gave Him to show to His servants the things that must soon take place. He made it known by sending His angel to His servant John,

Had Jesus fully shed His 'Man' state, then wouldn't He be back to just His 'fully God' essence; therefore would be omniscient and wouldn't need to be 'revealed to'?

Comment: "Had Jesus fully shed His 'Man' state" But why would Jesus do that?

Comment: The revelation of Jesus Christ is the revelation of the one born in Bethlehem, risen from the dead.

Comment: This question has occupied the minds of many theologians for 2000 years with much very heated debate; and you think that we will resolve it in this one question?  It is a good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jesus has forever united himself with humanity.  Though he is our Lord, and the power of God dwells within him, he will always be our elder Brother.

Remember what the disciples were told by the angels when Jesus ascended from them into Heaven?

> Which also said, Ye men of Galilee, why stand ye gazing up into
> heaven? **this same Jesus**, which is taken up from you into heaven, shall
> so come in like manner as ye have seen him go into heaven. (Acts 1:11,
> KJV)

Then we may also expect to see the "same Jesus" who once walked this earth in human form come again to us.

Comment: Up-voted +1 but I would go further than you do and say (Titus 2:13) _Our great God and Saviour - Jesus Christ_ .